# parámetros opcionales en instruccion between SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un formulario con dos parametros de busqueda que son fechas y se puede hacer el filtro por los dos parametros de fecha o solo de por uno, segun lo requiera el usurio, como puedo hacer la modifcicacion de mi query ya que uso between pero para esta instruccion son necesarios los dos parametros

```
SELECT pedidos.id
     , clientes.nombre
     , SUM( articulos.precio ) AS total
     ,clientes.FehaCompra
  FROM pedidos
INNER JOIN clientes
        ON clientes.id = pedidos.id_clientes
LEFT JOIN articulos
       ON articulos.id_pedidos = pedidos.id
WHERE clientes.FehaCompra BETWEEN 'opcional' AND 'opcional'
```

Comment: dificil que lo puedas resolver solo en el query ya que opcional es por lo que viene del formulario. Lo que puedes hacer es modificar tu código para que haga diferentes WHERE según los parametros que tomas en el formulario.  Depende del lenguaje que estes utilizando.

Comment: Declara un par de variables con valores by default y si le asignan una valor a alguna de éstas, sobreescribes el valor y listo.

Comment: Y donde queres hacer la modificacion? en el codigo que genera la query, es un SP? donde?

Comment: Cuándo el usuario ingresa una sola fecha, como se debe interpretar? Osea que significa para el usuario ingresar una sola fecha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He realizado consultas parecidas a lo que quieres. Generalmente las he hecho en procedimientos almacenados, pero igualmente puedes hacerlas en consultas planas.

En tu ejemplo, pones `opcional` tanto para el inicio como el fin de rango de fechas a consultar. Asumo que eso es por ser un ejemplo, porque en la realidad supongo que tienes dos variables distintas para cada valor, cierto?

Si es así, y tienes algo como `fecha1` y `fecha2`, entonces envías su valor a la consulta en esta forma:

```
WHERE
 (
  ('fecha1' <> '' AND 'fecha2' <> '' AND clientes.FehaCompra BETWEEN 'fecha1' AND 'fecha2')
 OR ('fecha1' <> '' AND 'fecha2' = '' AND clientes.FehaCompra >= 'fecha1')
 OR ('fecha1' = '' AND 'fecha2' <> '' AND clientes.FehaCompra <= 'fecha2')
 )
```

Esto en pseudocódigo sería:

1º Si el usuario llenó la fecha de inicio y la fecha de término, consulta usando el `BETWEEN`.

2º Si la condición anterior no se cumplió, pregunta si usuario llenó sólo fecha de inicio, entonces consulta por las fechas mayores o igual a la solicitada.

3º Si la condición anterior tampoco se cumplió, pregunta si usuario llenó sólo fecha de término, entonces consulta por las fechas menores o igual a la solicitada.

4º Si ninguna condición se cumplió, en teoría te devolverá todos los datos... (creo).

Importante: Fíjate en los paréntesis en los que envolví todas las condiciones. Eso es por si tienes más condiciones en tu `WHERE`, para que no se mezclen con tu condición por fechas.